# What are the differences between R quantile() estimator algorithms?

Tags: r, quantiles, estimators

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95007/explain-the-quantile-function-in-r) the answerer goes into what the R `quantile()` function generally does, but I don't really feel satisfied that I understand the different possible modes of the function.

I've been using quantile() to find the nth percentile of a set of data, as it turns out it was suggested in [the top answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15659528/how-to-get-nth-percentile-using-r-summary), but now that I'm looking into it further, I don't know how reliable that solution is.

I'm using the default type - type 7 - now, but the documentation for the function states that type 8 is the "recommended" type. Recommended for what? What is it finding, and how is that superior? Is it better for finding the percentiles?

I generally do not understand the difference between what exactly the different `quantile()` modes are finding. To make things even more confusing, my coworker ran a test of the two types and the percentiles produced by type 8 were not bijective, which would be impossible -- but I haven't been able to replicate his results, so I don't know how type 8 could or could not produce non-bijective percentiles.

Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: The documentation provides a reference. [Read it!](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original/Sample+Quantiles.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

[Hyndman and Fan (1996)](https://doi.org/10.2307/2684934) (also [here](https://www.amherst.edu/media/view/129116/original/Sample+Quantiles.pdf)) described 9 algorithms to calculate a quantile.

Sample quantiles of type i are defined by
`Q[i](p) = (1 - gamma) x[j] + gamma x[j+1]`

where `i in [1,9]`, `p in [(j-m)/n,(j-m+1)/ n]` , `x[j]` is the j-th order statistic, n is the sample size, and m is a constant determined by the sample quantile type. Here gamma depends on the fractional part of `g = np+m-j`.

For the continuous sample quantile types (4 through 9), the sample quantiles can be obtained by linear interpolation between the k-th order statistic and `p(k)`:

```
p(k) = (k - alpha) / (n - alpha - beta + 1)
```

where alpha and beta are constants determined by the type.
Further, `m = alpha + p(1 - alpha - beta)`, and `gamma = g`.

About the two types you are using (7 and 8, the default):

- Type 7 (used by S)

`p(k) = (k - 1) / (n - 1)` 
In this case, `p(k) = mode[F(x[k])]`.

- Type 8

`p(k) = (k - 1/3) / (n + 1/3)`

Then `p(k) =~ median[F(x[k])]`.
The resulting quantile estimates are approximately median-unbiased regardless of the distribution of 'x'.